Unnatural lighting on a rounded edge and corner
This rounded edge here looks weird and it's probably because it also has a rounded corner on both sides of it. I thought using the Weighted Normals modifier would help with this but it produces more weird shading around the corners. Is there a way to go about this? Preferably without remaking the whole object?
The first image shows the model with smooth shading, the second image shows what it looks like flat, which is what I want it to look like, but smoothed out.



Instead of using Shade Smooth use Auto Smooth. If it still doesn't look correct, go to the modifiers tab to the Smooth by Angle modifier and adjust the angle by decreasing or increasing until it looks better.
